# Missing posts by "others" for FQL stream table

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting mixed results with FQL and the open graph API when attempting to pull stream information on a page for filter_key = "others" I'm getting some posts, but some of them are just being omitted completely. The FQL statement that I'm running is...

```
SELECT message, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'other' AND source_id = 'XXX' LIMIT 25
```

If it helps, I'm ultimately trying to get all of the photos posted on the page by others (non-admin). This will include photos posted both on the Facebook website and mostly via FB mobile applications (iPhone, Android, etc).

All of the boxes under Admin -> Manage Permissions are checked for the page. Myself and another coworker have attempted to post photos to the wall with and without admin status (both scenarios posted as ourselves and not the page). My posts *will* show up in the return while his will not. Our individual privacy settings were different, so he changed his to 100% public. We had the same result (his posts didn't show up). There are several other posts on the wall (which show up under "Recent posts by others") that do not show up.

I've also deduced that posts made by *non-admins* through the iPhone app are **not** showing up in the stream for either of us. If I use filter_key = 'owner' I do see a few posts in there that were posted from "Facebook for iPhone", but if I remove my personal admin status and post using my iPhone, the post does not show up.

I'm pretty baffled. I'm not sure whether these are bugs or oversights on my part. Any ideas?